# applying a function to all the entries from a ; delimited column (map? pandas?)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame and would like to replace the values (delimiter = ";") of the third column.

`cat file.text`

> ```
> Name         ID        Values
> John         81-502    1
> Mike         81-501    2;2;2
> Matthew      81-512    1;0
> ```

```
def fun(x):
     return x+1
```

I would like to apply this function to replace the Values column in my dataframe such that:

`cat out.txt`

> ```
> Name         ID        Values
> John         81-502    2
> Mike         81-501    3;3;3
> Matthew      81-512    2;1
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary `split` values, convert to integers, add `1`, convert to strings and join back by `;`:

```
df['Values'] = df['Values'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(str(int(y) + 1) for y in x.split(';')))
```

Solution with list comprehension:

```
df['Values'] = [ ';'.join(str(int(y) + 1) for y in x.split(';')) for x in df['Values']]
```

---

```
print (df)
      Name      ID Values
0     John  81-502      2
1     Mike  81-501  3;3;3
2  Matthew  81-512    2;1
```

Comment: Quick issue! What if df['Values'][0]==NaN

Comment: @user171558 - then use `.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(str(int(y) + 1) for y in x.split(';')) if pd.notna(x) else np.nan)`

Comment: In my actual df, I have strings that I feed into a package function. and my values column consists of strings. Would it be ok if I used pd.NA instead of np.nan? After some reading, I assume they're very similar

Comment: @user171558 - I think it is same :)